# flask error: from app import views ImportError: cannot import name 'views'

Tags: python-3.x, flask

So I am just starting a project in flask and I am using the proper folder structure for the first time and I keep getting this error. I am confused as to why and haven't faced this problem before.

I have tried renaming files and using from . import views but to no avail.

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask
from app import views

app = Flask(__name__)
```

views.py

```py
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"
```

run.py

```py
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

Folder structure:

```
app
    static
    templates
    app.py
    run.py
    views.py

tmp
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in 
    from app import views
  File "/Users/Josh/PycharmProjects/web1/app/app.py", line 2, in 
    from app import views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views'

Answer (score 0):

app.py

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
import views
```

views.py

```py
from app import app

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

run.py

```py
from app import app

app.run(debug=True)
```